# Access to TextView in PlaceholderFragment from MainActivity

Tags: android, fragment, tabbed

I have an `Activity` (`MainActivity`) which contains a `Fragment` (`PlaceholderFragment`) with a `TextView` (`myTextView`) on it. I try to change `TextView`'s text from `MainActivity` via below code but always `myTextView` is `null`.

my  `MainActivity` class:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

          PlaceholderFragment myPlace =   mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPlaceholde(1);
          myPlace.setText("New Text");
          return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

my  `SectionsPagerAdapter` class:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment getPlaceholde(int position) {

      return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
}
```

my  `PlaceholderFragment` class:

```
 public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        TextView myTextView;

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {

        }

        public void setText(String s){

            if(myTextView!=null) {
                myTextView.setText(s);
            }else{
                Log.w("myTextView","NULL");    // problem is here: that this line is always launched
            }

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            myTextView =  (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            myTextView.setText("some text");//work well
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be in incorrect understanding of how [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) and [Fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle) works.

- Let's start from more basic thing: fragments lifecycle.
  When call `mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPlaceholde(1)` you're creating new fragment instance. At this moment Fragments' view is not created yet, so you observe `myTextView` as null. Based on Fragments' lifecycle a view get created only after [onCreateView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView%28android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle%29) callback after the fragment get attached to the activity. In your case this will never happen, because you're creating new fragment (by `mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPlaceholde(1)`) and not attaching it anywhere.
- Regarding `FragmentPagerAdapter`. It creates and caches fragments for you, so you don't need to create and attach every fragment by yourself - pager will keep it. Based on the code it looks like you want to update 1st fragment in the pager on some option selection. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager) on how to do it: basic idea is that you need to override two methods from `ViewPager` in order to know fragments name and be able to find it using [FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag%28java.lang.String%29).